# Define sensor properties

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have connected my arduino a sensor and I needed help with making it read vertical movement and if it goes off the required and the sensor make a noise letting the user now to leave the production a vertical position

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly is your question? It seems unclear from your post.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of sensor is it? if its something like a PIR movement sensor it wont work since it only detects change in heat